# Linear Algebra Matrix Equation Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A\in  \mathbb R^{n×n}$ , $B\in  \mathbb R^{n×n}$, Show that if $I + AB$ is nonsingular then

$\left ( I+AB \right )^{-1}=I-A\left ( I+BA \right )^{-1}B$

Comment: How about multiplying the RHS by $I+AB$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes but I cannot seem to simplify the RHS afterwards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Hint:-**

```
A matrix A is non-singular iff it is invertible.
```

Since $I+AB$ is nonsingular implies, it is invertible.

Using $series$ $expansion$
$$(I+BA)^{-1}=I-BA+(BA)(BA)-(BA)(BA)(BA)+\cdots$$
$$A(I+BA)^{-1}B=AB-(AB)(AB)+(AB)(AB)(AB)+(AB)(AB)(AB)(AB)+\dots$$
$$A(I+BA)^{-1}B=-(I+AB)^{-1}+I$$
$$(I+AB)^{-1}=I-A(I+BA)^{-1}B$$

Comment: Could you please explain the process you use? I'm not sure I understand it, thank you.

Comment: I think the expansion of (I+BA)^-1 you are not getting right??

Comment: I made it clear . After that step I am just pre-multiplied  by A and post-multiplied  by  B both the side and simple calculation will led you to the answer.